# exp() returns NaN stuff

Tags: php, nan, exp

Ok, I'm stuck. I have this PHP code:

```
    echo exp(12), '<br/>';
    echo exp(4.2);
```

just like on the PHP.net page. And what I have on the screen:

```
    NAN
    298.86740096706
```

but then there comes the weirdest thing ever. I thought that maybe there's some PHP.ini problem with numbers like 2.67e8 and so (I mean with the 'e' inside) or something. But then, when I changed the above code into:

```
    echo (2.67e8), '<br/>';
    echo exp(4.2);
```

suddenly I saw this whatever:

```
    267000000
    NAN
```

It's kind of WTF especially because of the last NAN, when first it was a quite normal, calm float 298.86740096706 but then just with no reason it went to hell replaced by NAN. Do you have any ideas? Please?

Comment: Could not duplicate issue. `php -r "echo exp(12), '<br/>'; echo exp(4.2);"` = `162754.791419<br/>66.686331040925`. Using `PHP 5.3.10`

Comment: I tried as well:  
`php > echo exp(12) . "\n" . exp(4.2) . "\n";`  
`162754.791419  
66.686331040925`  
PHP 5.4.3 on Arch Linux

Comment: Is the code you wrote your code, all your code, exactly your code and nothing but your code?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg it's the 5.3.5

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yes, that's all i wrote. beside this are only the "<?php" and "?>"

Comment: @OP: can you replicate this behaviour? Does it bug out on every execution? Is the result/phenomenon different at certain executions?

Comment: @TaZ actually, it sometimes displays 298.86740096706 instead of NAN in the second code. but it's like 1 per 30 refreshes or something around

Comment: I tested this like so: `while (true) { echo exp(12) . ' ' . exp(4.2) . "\n"; sleep(1); }` in my terminal and it's very consistent. Did not test on web server.

Comment: Ok, now I tried to loop it in this way: `do { $c=exp(4.2); echo 'point '; } while (is_nan($c));` and i've got `point point 66.686331040925` so it kind of works but still in a strange, slow way

Comment: Perhaps the server is running out of memory, did you try restarting apache & php, and increasing memory_limit?

Comment: @Mahn increased twice and restarted, still the same - two `point ` echoes and then the actual number

Comment: @user1390266 `do { $c=exp(4.2); echo 'point '; } while (is_nan($c));` would not print out the actually number. How could that code print 66.68633104...?

Comment: All this back and forth, and he still hasn't told us the version of PHP causing this issue.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg the code is `do { $c=exp(4.2); echo 'point '; } while (is_nan($c)); echo $c;`

Comment: @MikePurcell it's the 5.3.5, i wrote it

Comment: @user1390266: You wrote what?

Comment: @MikePurcell in an earlier comment he wrote that it's 5.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

If true, this must be a bug in your PHP version.  Please [report it](https://bugs.php.net/report.php).

By the way, I'm unable to reproduce it on PHP 5.3.2.  Running:

```sh
php -r 'do { $c = exp(4.2); echo "point "; } while (is_nan($c)); echo "$c\n";'
```

produces the expected output:

```
point 66.686331040925
```

Comment: or he could just try to install a newer version first, then report it if the problem still exists...